# How to groupby and perform custom calculation

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe - `df` as below :

```
Stud_id card    Nation  Gender  Age  Code   Amount  yearmonth
111     1       India   M      Adult 543    100     201601
111     1       India   M      Adult 543    100     201601
111     1       India   M      Adult 543    150     201602
111     1       India   M      Adult 612    100     201602
111     1       India   M      Adult 715    200     201603
222     2       India   M      Adult 715    200     201601
222     2       India   M      Adult 543    100     201604
222     2       India   M      Adult 543    100     201603
333     3       India   M      Adult 543    100     201601
333     3       India   M      Adult 543    100     201601
333     4       India   M      Adult 543    150     201602
333     4       India   M      Adult 612    100     201607
```

Now, I want two dataframes as below :

`df_1` :

```
card    Code    Total_Amount    Avg_Amount
1       543     350             175
2       543     200             100
3       543     200             200
4       543     150             150
1       612     100             100
4       612     100             100
1       715     200             200
2       715     200             200
```

Logic for `df_1` :

1. `Total_Amount` : For each unique `card` and unique `Code` get the sum of amount  ( For eg : `card` : `1` , `Code` : `543 = 350` )
2. `Avg_Amount`: Divide the Total amount by no.of unique `yearmonth` for each unique `card` and unique `Code`  ( For eg : `Total_Amount` = `350`, No. Of unique `yearmonth` is `2 = 175`

`df_2` :

```
Code    Avg_Amount
543     156.25
612     100
715     200
```

Logic for `df_2` :

1. `Avg_Amount`: Sum of `Avg_Amount` of each `Code` in `df_1` (For eg. `Code`:`543` the Sum of `Avg_Amount` is `175+100+200+150 = 625`. Divide it by no.of rows - `4`. So `625/4 = 156.25`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df1 = df.groupby(['card','Code'])['yearmonth','Amount'].apply(lambda x: [sum(x.Amount),sum(x.Amount)/len(set(x.yearmonth))]).apply(pd.Series).reset_index()

df1.columns= ['card','Code','Total_Amount','Avg_Amount']
```

**Output**

```
   card  Code  Total_Amount  Avg_Amount
0     1   543           350       175.0
1     1   612           100       100.0
2     1   715           200       200.0
3     2   543           200       100.0
4     2   715           200       200.0
5     3   543           200       200.0
6     4   543           150       150.0
7     4   612           100       100.0
```

For Second

```
df2 = df1.groupby('Code')['Avg_Amount'].apply(lambda x: sum(x)/len(x)).reset_index(name='Avg_Amount')
```

**Output**

```
   Code  Avg_Amount
0   543      156.25
1   612      100.00
2   715      200.00
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works. But since my data is huge its taking lot of time. Apply takes lot of time, Is there a optimized way ?

Comment: might be because of too many groups..will have to look, but you can try numpy here might improve your execution time.